# WebSocket connection to 'wss://129-227-205-149.edge.agora.io:4714/' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I'm using Agora.io web sdk(AgoraRTC_N-4.16.1.js) to build a video chat app and the websocket keeps on failing before establishing a connection. The error is shown in the AgoraRTC_N-4.16.1.js file.

```
let joinAndDisplayLocalStream = async () => {
    client.on('user-published', () => {
        console.log("user has joined the room")
    })
    await client.join(APP_ID, CHANNEL, TOKEN, UID)

    localTracks = await AgoraRTC.createMicrophoneAndCameraTracks()

    let player = `<div class="video-container" id="user-container-${UID}">
                        <div class="username-wrapper"><span class="user-name">My Name</span></div>
                        <div class="video-player" id="user-${UID}"></div>
                    </div>`
    
    document.getElementById('video-streams').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', player)

    localTracks[1].play(`user-${UID}`) 

    await client.publish(localTracks[0], localTracks[1])
  }
```

I rolled back the the SDK version and still getting the same error. What could be the possible reason.[image]